# Are there union rules requiring stunt performers, and what does this mean for action stars who "do their own stunts"?

Tags: production, stunts, legal

In an answer to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/how-are-head-shots-and-deep-throat-gashes-filmed), it is mentioned offhand:

> There are almost no "live shots" of this as it is technically a stunt and according to union rules ( at least in Hollywood) that requires a stunt performer.

But we often hear about actors, especially big name stars, who "do their own stunts". Is there some exemption for leading roles? Is it something that actors are always allowed to freely choose, but directors may not coerce them to do? Is it one of those more technical union rules where it doesn't matter who physically performs as long as someone from the stunt performers' union gets paid?